# Citynames with Postalcodes data

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the city names for my autocompletion script.

Here is a working example. This website in created in Joomla using Sobi2

http://pizzabrowser.de/

If I type a city name in the inputbox a suggestions list will be displayed.

for example if I type in "Offenbach" it will display the city Offenbach along with it wards.

Does anyone know if such data is available anywhere?

Comment: UK? US? Rest of the world? There is a database of UK postcodes available on the net for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for city and other geographic names [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) may be a good starting point.

**About GeoNames**

> The GeoNames geographical database is available for download free of
>   charge under a creative commons attribution license. It contains over
>   10 million geographical names and consists of 7.5 million unique
>   features whereof 2.8 million populated places and 5.5 million
>   alternate names.

Don't forget that [You can support the Geonames.org project and make a donation via paypal.](http://www.geonames.org/donations.html).